# Expected DWM behavior when an app goes full-screen

Tags: windows, directx, fullscreen, multiple-monitors, dwm

**Q1**: What is the **expected behavior** of **DWM** in **multi-monitor** setup (extended) when one of monitors is covered by a **full-screen** (D3D11) application (*not* a maximized borderless window)?
 1. all remaining screens should be blank
 2. all remaining screens should be actively refreshed
 3. ?

**Q2**: Should/can applications setup DWM's behavior anyhow when they go full-screen (I mean: force it to do 1/2/3)?

I've read [DXGI: Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee417025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but it does not really consider DWM coexisting with a full-screen app in a multi-monitor setup.

**Additional info:**
I can see DWM behaving differently in such cases depending on the particular app (mine or 3rd party), the machine app is run on or even a particular run of the same app on the same machine. Googling reveals that I'm not the only one who's experienced these inconsistencies, e.g.:
a) [gaming.stackexchange.com](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170795/is-it-possible-to-have-a-second-monitor-that-is-unaffected-by-fullscreen-games-o) - contents of the second screen shifted
b) [forums.geforce.com](https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/520006/2nd-monitor-going-black-when-playing-game-fullscreen/) - second monitor blank

Thanks,
kalesony

Comment: **Play a game on a dual-monitor setup and you'll see how it works.** One display minds its own business while the game is full-screen on the other display. That's how I read my email while playing. Mail client opened on other screen. Unless I click on it, focus is not lost and full screen app sticks.

Comment: CodeAngry: thanks for quick reply but in my experience this is not always the case so either the behavior you've described is *not guaranteed* (and this is part of my question) or zap is right and your game is actually running in a maximized borderless window.

Comment: Read my comment to zap's answer. I've played games for 10+ years and never has the second screen been blank or something like that.

Comment: CodeAngry: all I can say is that my experience is different. I have extended my question so that it briefly describes the issue I'm facing and provides external references.

Answer (score 0):

CodeAngry: you've described behavior when application is using maximized, borderless window, not a "real full-screen" as mentioned in question.

Comment: You should play some Battlefield 4 in full-screen (not windowed, not borderless) than come back with a comment. And open your Battlemap on your other display in the browser.